# Why isn't my reputation count raising when my post gets upvoted on meta?

Tags: discussion, reputation, up-votes

### Here's my problem:

I've had some upvoted posts that **haven't raised my reputation count.** It will sometimes **take some time** to notify me and raise my reputation count, but ***it's been 36 hours, and still no notification.***

**Here's a couple of upvoted posts that haven't raised my reputation count:**

- [Why I can only vote 36 times in a day?](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1612/why-i-can-only-vote-36-times-in-a-day)
- [What is a reasonable reputation count?](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1605/what-is-a-reasonable-reputation-count)

It might just be another bug, but it could also be what is *meant* to happen.

### Here's my theory:

It could just be **whatever changes are made to you're reputation count on the main site *(in this case it's [earthscience.se](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/))* is what happens to your reputation count on meta.**

> If my theory os **correct,** than it would be much appreciated it i was **told so.** But if my theory is **incorrect,** than I ask for **answers that tell me what's really going on.**

**Thanks for understanding :)**

Comment: To quote the [What is meta?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) help page: `Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Earth Science Stack Exchange (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.`

Comment: Incidentally: if it's important to you to acquire a high reputation score, Earth Science is not a good stackexchange for you. Firstly, the topics are mostly technical and can require a lot of expertise, time, and effort to address. Secondly, even good, high-effort questions and answers often get few votes simply because there are few active users here. By comparison, sites like [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/) and [English Language](https://english.stackexchange.com/) provide more reputation in less time, because they have more users and because posts are often quicker to write.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meta does not contribute to your reputation.  The reputation you see on meta is just whatever your rep on the main site is.

Based on this and your linked questions, you are a bit obsessed about reputation.  Don't focus on fake internet points, just participate in the site in a natural, organic way.  If you are contributing to the site in a positive way, you'll gain reputation.  Don't go out of your way to game the system (as much as its design promotes it).  Focus on providing good content.